# revolution slider reveal text

Tags: slider, revolution-slider

I am using revolution slider to animate an image from left to right on the screen (this part is working).   I would like to have a layer of text that appears as the image crosses over it.   Is there a way to do this with slider revolution?

Answer (score 0):

```
             <ul>
                 <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
                 <li data-transition="curtain-1" data-slotamount="5" data-masterspeed="700" data-title="Slide 1">
                     <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                     <img src="yourIMGhere.jpg" 
                     alt="slidebg1" data-bgfit="cover" 
                     data-bgposition="center center" 
                     data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">

                     <!-- LAYERS -->
                     <div class="tp-caption rs-caption-1 sft start"
                     data-x="center"
                     data-hoffset="0"
                     data-y="100"
                     data-speed="800"
                     data-start="2000"
                     data-easing="Back.easeInOut"
                     data-endspeed="300">
                     <u>TEXT PLACED HERE FOR FIRST LAYER</u>
                 </div>

                 <!-- LAYER -->
                 <div class="tp-caption rs-caption-2 sft"
                 data-x="center"
                 data-hoffset="0"
                 data-y="200"
                 data-speed="1000"
                 data-start="3000"
                 data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                 data-endspeed="300"
                 data-endeasing="Power1.easeIn"
                 data-captionhidden="off"
                 style="z-index: 6">
                 ADD A SECOND LAYER OF TEXT HERE THAT COMES IN AT NEW TIME
             </div>

             <!-- LAYER -->
             <div class="tp-caption rs-caption-3 sft"
             data-x="center"
             data-hoffset="0"
             data-y="360"
             data-speed="800"
             data-start="3500"
             data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
             data-endspeed="300"
             data-endeasing="Power1.easeIn"
             data-captionhidden="off"
             style="z-index: 6">
             THIRD LAYER HERE AND SO ON... 
         </div>
     </li>
```

obviously adjust the settings for each layer according to your needs but that's how to add multiple layers that'll appear at different times... hope it helps